# How to get product count from a filtered product collection specific to category

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I have below script of product collection :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection = $collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
// here I have some custom attribute filter
$collection_array = $collection->getData();
$categoryids = array_column($collection_array, 'category_id');
$categoryids = array_unique($categoryids);
foreach($categoryids as $categoryId) 
{
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    // here I want to count product from $collection which are in $_category
}
```

How to get products count from product collection for each category?

Comment: you want get number of products from each categories ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection = $collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
// here I have some custom attribute filter
$collection_array = $collection->getData();

$pIds = [];
foreach($collection_array as $pid) :
    $pIds[] = $pid['entity_id'];
endforeach;

$categoryids = array_column($collection_array, 'category_id');

$categoryids = array_unique($categoryids);
$catIds = sort($categoryids);

foreach($categoryids as $categoryId) 
{
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $products_count = $_category->getProductCount();

    $prodCollection = $_category->getProductCollection();
    $prodCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $c = 0; 
    foreach ($prodCollection as $_product) {

        if (in_array($_product->getId(), $pIds)) {
            $c++;
        }
    }
    echo($_category->getName().' ( '.$c). ' ) <br/>';
    $c = 0; 
}
```

Comment: I want to get product count which are in $collection not all product count.

Comment: I have update my answer. Please check and let me know .

Comment: Hello, it is working but it is taking to much time in nested loop, I have greater than 40,000 products in my magento store. I upvoted your answer for give me hint.Thanks.

Comment: It is better to use php functions `array_column`, `array_intersect` in place of loop.